# How should I code my event handler for my C# Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I am currently developing a C# Windows Form Application that I intend to let it interact with a server. The server will receive posting from a mobile application that I have developed and whenever a posting is received, my Windows Form Application should be notified and give me a notification.

E.g. My mobile application sends an message over to my server. Once my server receives the message, my windows form application should display a new notification showing the content of the message received.

The above scenario is just a example of what I intend to do with the whole thing. Any idea how should I code my C# application in order to receive the information as stated above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement a WCF Service inside your server. You Windows Form application can be your WCF Service client.

What you probably want is a [Duplex Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx)

They way this would work is

1. WCF Service in running on your server
2. Windows Form connects to your server WCF service using Duplex Contract
3. Mobile app posts to server
4. WCF Service knows about it and using the call back channel notifies the WCF Client
5. Your Form Application aka WCF Client updates UI with this new message received

Comment: hi. thank you for your reply. regarding step 4, how does the service knows whenever the mobile app post to the server?

Comment: @Thomas without the details on the mobile app plaform it is difficult to answer. Can you connect to a standard webservice from mobile app ? Maybe you can expose that from server

Comment: when the server receives a posting, it will invoke a method from the WCF service to say that it has send a posting and sends the information over. Once the method is being called, (Step 4), the wcf service will receive the information. But from there on, how does it send the information to a 2nd client using the call back channel?

Comment: oh. my mistake. must have clicked wrongly. didnt meant to do that.

Comment: A typical way is for the server to keep track of all call back channels. So when the mobile app posts... the server will have to notify all call back channels

Comment: just to confirm once again, does duplex service really work the way I want as stated above or must I change it to a publish/subscribe service. thanks again for your reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answer @parapura rajkumar, you could also investigate a [Message Queue architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue), where the messages posted back from the mobile app are visible to both the server and the Windows client.

Perhaps a little more heavy-weight but certainly worth consideration, especially if you suspect the application may need to grow in complexity in the future...